# Set meta_query only for specific post type

Tags: custom-post-types, woocommerce-offtopic, search

I'm trying to hide my Woocommerce products that are out of stock from search, while still showing other post types in the results. The **post type** for the products are `product`.

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'hide_out_of_stock_from_search' );

function hide_out_of_stock_from_search( $q ) {

    if ( ! $q->is_search() ) return;
    if ( is_post_type_archive( 'product' ) ) {

        $q->set( 'meta_query', array(array(
            'key'       => '_stock_status',
            'value'     => 'outofstock',
            'compare'   => 'NOT IN'
        )));

    }

    remove_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'hide_out_of_stock_from_search' );
}
```

Everything is working except `is_post_type_archive( 'product' )`, which doesn't return true. If I replace it with true, it hide everything from search query (even posts and pages) except products that are in stock.

How can I set meta_query only for a specific post type without affecting other post types in the search query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Quick explanation

Search is search and not an archive.

If you'll take a look at [`is_post_type_archive`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_post_type_archive) docs, you'll see that it:

> Checks if the query is for an archive page of a given post type(s).

So if you're using this condition in your `pre_get_posts`, then it won't affect search results at all.

On the other hand this meta_query:

```
$q->set( 'meta_query', array(array(
    'key'       => '_stock_status',
    'value'     => 'outofstock',
    'compare'   => 'NOT IN'
)));
```

tells that you want to get only posts that have this meta value set and different than `outoofstock`, so it will exclude all posts and pages (because they don't have such meta value at all).

### Solution

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'hide_out_of_stock_from_search' );

function hide_out_of_stock_from_search( $q ) {

    if ( ! is_admin() && $q->is_main_query() && $q->is_search() ) {

        $q->set( 'meta_query', array(
            'relation' => 'OR',
            array(
                'key'       => '_stock_status',
                'value'     => 'outofstock',
                'compare'   => 'NOT IN'
            ),
            array(
                'key'       => '_stock_status',
                'compare'   => 'NOT EXISTS'
            )
        ));

    }
}
```

Comment: Your explanation makes sense, and solution works. Thanks!